# Best way to search for events?

Tags: ios, eventkit, ekevent

I want to give my users an option to search in events - title, location, notes, etc. What's the best way to do that? Just fetch all events to the next 2 years, but how to make the search without slowing things up?

Answer (score 0):

Register for notification also called local notifications.Use the NSLocalNotification it will give the required alerts for events.